# Change home subdirectories' language

Tags: home, language

When I was installing manjaro, I set OS's language to persian (my mother tongue). So home's subdirs' names are persian. How can I change their names to english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your desktop environment's language to English. (I don't know whether you're using Manjaro plasma desktop, xfce desktop or gnome desktop. But all of these have a settings dialog where you can change the language.)

If you don't want to change the language: Rename the folders as you want them to be named. Afterwards, run

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set NAME NEW_PATH
```

where *`NAME`* is `DESKTOP`, `DOWNLOAD`, `TEMPLATES`, `PUBLICSHARE`, `DOCUMENTS`, `MUSIC`, `PICTURES` or `VIDEOS` (and describes the thing whose directory you want to change), and *`NEW_PATH`* should be the new path – ideally, something like `'$HOME/Desktop'`, `'$HOME/Download'`, `'$HOME/Templates'`, ….

The file /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults should contain the default English folder names to be used after `$HOME/` on your Linux distro.